# preferredContentSize not working instead of contentSizeForViewInPopover

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am working on project where i want to make my app compatible with IOS7.

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(90, 1 * 65 - 1);
```

this method is deprecated from ios7

new method is `self.preferredContentSize= CGSizeMake(90,1*65-1);`

but i am not getting proper UI[image]

but when i am changing with ios7 compatiable method my view is like this

with ios7 method i am getting this
 [image]

Comment: Where are you setting `self.preferredContentSize`?

Comment: @SamStigler i have same problem, i put it to `viewWillAppear`, but nothing happend.

Comment: @Waki Could you try overriding the -preferredContentSize method instead, and putting your calculations etc. inside there? Let me know if that works.

Comment: @SamStigler i try set to `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` but nothing happened. When Popover showing first time size is correct, but when i push to another view in popover (with bigger size) and when return back, size popover not set.

Answer (score 7):

This is given in apple documentation:

> This property allows direction manipulation of the content size of the popover. Changing the property directly is equivalent to animated=YES. The content size is limited to a minimum width of 320 and a maximum width of 600.

```
@property (nonatomic) CGSize popoverContentSize;

- (void)setPopoverContentSize:(CGSize)size animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

I have implemented to handle the content size of popover like this & its working:

```
self.popController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(430, 460);
```

Comment: Isn't this kind of dirty to have a property within the popover view controller to just adjust it's size? Is there no better way?